# Salesforce Aura lightning:checkboxGroup

Tags: javascript, aura, javascript-controller, lightning-checkbox-group

I have an existing Aura component that I need to add some help text to. I have a `lightning:checkboxGroup` that I need to add some help text to one of the options. The code is below. What I need to do is add red text to the end of `option2`. With Javascript I could start at the div surrounding the checkboxgroup and then navigate through the children to find the component then add `<span style="color:red;">help text</span>` to the end of the label. Is there a way to do something the same using `cmp.find`? I tried

```xml
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="[
        {'label': 'Option1','value': 'Option1'},
        {'label': 'Option2','value': 'Option2'},
        {'label': 'Option3','value': 'Option3'},
        
    ]" />
    <div aura:id="checkboxGroup" class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1">
        <lightning:checkboxGroup
            name="checkbox"
            label=""
            options="{! v.options }"
            value="{! v.checkboxValue }"
            onchange="{! c.handleChange }"
            class="slds-checkbox-horizontally"
        />
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

```javascript
handleChange : function (cmp, event, helper) {

    //this returns an item but I can't find the children to get down to the label I need
    var b = cmp.find("checkboxGroup");
    console.log("*****b = " + b);

    //this does not return anything
    var a = Document.getElementByClass("slds-form-element__label");
    console.log("*****a = " + a);
}
```

Comment: You can't look inside most of the `lightning` components provided by Salesforce - they are mostly lwc components now. Also, change `var a = Document.getElementByClass("slds-form-element__label");` to `var a = document.getElementByClassName("slds-form-element__label");` (case sensitivity, wrong name). If you do want to modify the internals of another component, you could use/adapt my component: https://github.com/rapsacnz/RadioGroup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the [developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_dom.htm)

> A component can only traverse the DOM and access elements created by a
> component in the same namespace. This behavior prevents the
> anti-pattern of reaching into DOM elements owned by components in
> another namespace.

Your component is in `c` namespace, while *checkboxGroup* element is in `lightning` namespace. You can't reach into this base lightning component and modify the HTML within it. Consider doing one of the following:

1. Build your own custom component (refer [slds](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/checkbox/#Required-with-help-text-with-tooltip) for styling and relevant HTML elements. *The component source code provided by @CasperHarmer seems like a good place to start with.*
2. Use `title` attribute to display tooltip (generic) text when the mouse moves over the element.
3. Insert HTML element inside the `div` (*below or above `lightning:checkboxGroup` element*) to display a generic help text